# Excel VBA Getting value on One sheet to be parameter for search results on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called *"lookup"* and in cell B2 of that sheet, users can input a department code (ex: 190) and select a "Search" button:
[image]

Once they hit the search button it will take them to a sheet called *"department_lookup"* which in column A has account codes with the department code 190 in it and in column B has the account code description. In cell C1, though, I want to have the value being searched for populate cell C1 that way the query in sheet "department_lookup" can refresh to show proper data.  Here is what sheet *"department_lookup"* looks like:
[image]

In column A & B would be a list depending on how many account codes have the department code 190 in it.

Essentially, the data in sheet *department_lookup* is a dynamic query and I'd like cell C1 to be the parameter value that alters the query to display the account codes that the user is searching for in cell B2 in the sheet *lookup*.

Here's the code I have for sheet *lookup*:

```
On Error GoTo Done:
        If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Cancel = True
            mycell = Sheets("department_lookup").Range("$C$1").Value
            If mycell = " " Then GoTo Done:
            Sheets("department_lookup").Activate
        End If
Sheets("acct_codes").Visible = False
Sheets("dept_list").Visible = False 
Cancel = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True               
End Sub
```

Here is the vba i have for sheet *department_lookup*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("deptlookup").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "select seg1_code+'-'+seg2_code+'-'+seg3_code+'-'+seg4_code as account_code, account_description from glchart as GL where GL.inactive_flag = 0 and seg2_code='" & Range("C1").Value & "' order by seg1_code"
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("deptlookup").Refresh
End If
End Sub
```

Currently, when I manually change the value of cell C1 to a different department code, the query in *department_lookup* will change to display the proper codes but, I think my issue is properly setting C1 to equal whatever the user searched for in cell B2 in sheet *lookup*. Can anyone help out with this?

Comment: Just add this line to your code for your Search button:
`Worksheets("department_lookup").Range("C1").Value = Worksheets("lookup").Range("B2").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set that sheet's c1 to equal the cell of your initial sheet upon click of the submit button, then filter per C1 such as:

```
Sheets("department_lookup").Cells(1, 3).Value = Sheets("lookup").Cells(2, 2).Value
With Sheets("department_lookup")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=.Cells(1, 3).Value, VisibleDropDown:=True
End With
```

You would define the LR as the last row and the LC as last column.

Comment: You use cell C1 twice, on one sheet the value is in B2

Comment: @Luuklag Fixed.  Also corrected for his sheet names.

Comment: @Cyril Thanks so much for your answer. should I place this code in the lookup sheet?

Comment: @anve You should put this in the execution for pushing "Search"

Comment: @Cyril Thanks! I think I understand. Place the vba in the macro assigned to the Search button, correct?

Comment: @Cyril I added it to the macro and that worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @Cyril, when I click the "Search" button, I get a run time 1004: application or object defined error message. When I debug it highlights `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=.Cells(1, 3).Value, VisibleDropDown:=True` as the issue. Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: @anve The LR and LC are to be user defined.  Essentially they are variables until you give them values.  You need to determine what you need in those fields.